# libusb: error [submit_bulk_transfer] submiturb failed error -1 errno=2 - What am I doing wrong with LibUSB?

Tags: c++, c, libusb

Ok, I'm probably doing something dumb, but I can't get libusb to let me transfer data to my device for the life of me.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>


#define EP_DATA_IN  0x83
#define EP_DATA_OUT 0x02
#define DEVICE_CONFIGURATION 0


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int rc;
    libusb_context *ctx = NULL;
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle;

    int actual = 0;
    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[4];
    data[0]='a';data[1]='b';data[2]='c';data[3]='d';

    rc = libusb_init(&ctx);
    if(rc < 0) {
        std::cout << "Init Error " << rc << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    libusb_set_debug(ctx, 6);


    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, 0x03eb, 0x2423);
    if (!dev_handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(dev_handle, DEVICE_CONFIGURATION) == 1) {
        std::cout << "Kernel Driver Active" << std::endl;
        if(libusb_detach_kernel_driver(dev_handle, DEVICE_CONFIGURATION) == 0)
            std::cout << "Kernel Driver Detached!" << std::endl;
    }

    rc = libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle, DEVICE_CONFIGURATION);
    if(rc != 0) {
        std::cout << "Cannot Claim Interface" << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }

    std::cout << "Data->" << data << "<-" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Writing Data..." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Trying endpoint " << EP_DATA_OUT << "." << std::endl;
    rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, EP_DATA_OUT, data, sizeof(data), &actual, 100);

    if(rc == 0 && actual == 4)
    {
        std::cout << "Writing Successful!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Write Error! Rc: " << rc << " Actual transfered bytes: " << actual << "." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Error code means: " << libusb_error_name(rc) << std::endl;
    }


    rc = libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0);
    if(rc!=0) {
        std::cout << "Cannot Release Interface" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (dev_handle)
        libusb_close(dev_handle);

    libusb_exit(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Device in question:

```
pi@testpi:~$ sudo lsusb -d 03eb: -v

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03eb:2423 Atmel Corp.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x03eb Atmel Corp.
  idProduct          0x2423
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 ATMEL ASF
  iProduct                2 Vendor Class Example
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           69
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           6
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

And what I get when I run the code against the device:

```
pi@testpi:~/BatLogger/Interface/libusb_test$ ./make.sh
libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_list]
libusb: debug [libusb_get_device_descriptor]
libusb: debug [libusb_open] open 1.4
libusb: debug [usbi_add_pollfd] add fd 11 events 4
libusb: debug [libusb_kernel_driver_active] interface 0
libusb: debug [libusb_claim_interface] interface 0
Data->abcd<-
Writing Data...
Trying endpoint 2.
libusb: debug [add_to_flying_list] arm timerfd for timeout in 100ms (first in line)
libusb: debug [submit_bulk_transfer] need 1 urbs for new transfer with length 4
libusb: error [submit_bulk_transfer] submiturb failed error -1 errno=2
libusb: debug [submit_bulk_transfer] first URB failed, easy peasy
libusb: debug [disarm_timerfd]
Write Error! Rc: -1 Actual transfered bytes: 0.
Error code means: LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
libusb: debug [libusb_release_interface] interface 0
libusb: debug [libusb_close]
libusb: debug [usbi_remove_pollfd] remove fd 11
libusb: debug [libusb_exit]
libusb: debug [libusb_exit] destroying default context
```

As far as I know, I'm doing everything correctly. `libusb_claim_interface` returns OK, there isn't a pre-existing driver attached to the device since I'm using a custom VID/PID combo, and `EP_DATA_OUT` is a output endpoint (direction bit is 0, though to whom "out" is with respect to isn't described). Out of irritation, I've also tried every other possible endpoint (0-16, 0-16 | 1 << 7), with the exact same error for all of them.

Is there something silly I'm missing? Do I have to install a kernel module or something to make libusb play nice with me? I'm using libusb-1.0.

The error from the libusb debug message is `error -1 errno=2`. where `errno=2` corresponds to ERNOENT, but the few things I could find about that together with libusb didn't have a decent conclusion about what's actually going on.

Code is built `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -lrt -lusb-1.0 main.cpp -o main.bin`, though the fact that I'm using C++ is *probably* not relevant to the issue, since I'm not using one of the C++ libusb wrappers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the issue.

Basically, apparently, for ~*reasons*~, the endpoints for my device are attached to configuration 0, *alternate setting 1*.

I'm not sure how, or if it's even possible to determine this from the output of `lsusb`, but I had a bit of scripting that I had used for a different device written against PyUSB, so I had a poke around with that, and it told me:

```
1 pi@testpi:~/BatLogger/Interface/libusb_test$ sudo python3 test.py
INFO:Main.Gui:Device: DEVICE ID 03eb:2423 on Bus 001 Address 004 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x03eb
 idProduct              : 0x2423
 bcdDevice              :  0x100 Device 1.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 ATMEL ASF
 iProduct               :    0x2 Vendor Class Example
 iSerialNumber          :    0x0
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x45 (69 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Vendor Specific ===========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xff
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0xff
     iInterface         :    0x0
    INTERFACE 0, 1: Vendor Specific ========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x6
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xff
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0xff
     iInterface         :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Interrupt OUT ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
      ENDPOINT 0x83: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x83 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x4: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x4 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x85: Isochronous IN ========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x85 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x100 (256 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
      ENDPOINT 0x6: Isochronous OUT ========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x6 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x1 Isochronous
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x100 (256 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
```

The critical thing being that there are no endpoints under `INTERFACE 0:`, but there *are* endpoints under `INTERFACE 0, 1:`. This was enough to go on to figure out that there were more then one version of `INTERFACE 0`, and with that, it was pretty easy to figure out I needed to call `libusb_set_interface_alt_setting()` to select the right alternate configuration thingie.

Basically, I wound up adding

```
rc = libusb_set_interface_alt_setting(dev_handle, DEVICE_CONFIGURATION, 1);
if(rc != 0) {
    std::cout << "Cannot configure alternate setting" << std::endl;
    return 3;
}
```

after the `libusb_claim_interface()` call in my C(++) code, and I can now write to the device.